# How can I open firefox in normal mode with Selenium? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I want to work in normal mode using Selenium with Python in the Firefox browser. However, when I write the codes in this way, the test mode always turns on. Is there a way to boot into normal mode?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://github.com")
```

Comment: What do you mean by test mode in Firefox, explain in detail.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/zKdqOFmQvcvz like this.